# Customize MUI X DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, mui-x

I am using the DatePicker in a project, but I need to customize it to look like this:
[image: design image]

I looked at the API and I found some customization options but the month and year selector are not there. Is this possible or do I need to implement a custom component for this.